# Reading from a Database in a remote Server using UCanAccess and Apache Commons Net

Tags: java, database, networking, ucanaccess

I have a java application that needs to read from a database.
I was able to do this simply by using the UCanAccess driver to read .accdb files (Microsoft Access).

```
public boolean connect()
{
    System.out.println("\n\nconnecting to database......\n\n");
    try { //connect to the database
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/C92/Desktop/Database1.accdb");
            st = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
            return false;
        }
}
```

I also have a Client program that connects to a server (run by FileZilla) using Apache Commons Net to transfer files from server to the client.

```
ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    ftpClient.connect(serverName, 21);
    ftpClient.login(user, pass);
    ftpClient.enterLocalPassiveMode();
    ftpClient.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
```

The problem begins when I want to read from that database, but this time placed on the server that I am connected to. I don't know how to combine both implementations (Apache Commons Net and UCanAccess) to read a .accdb file in a server.

Please if you are familiar with networking you may be able to help me with this. Thank you!

Comment: Presumably that `FTPClient()` object will download the file from the server, so just download the file to a known location (e.g., using `java.io.File.createTempFile`) and then include the absolute path to the local copy in the JDBC connection URL.

Comment: Thanks, @GordThompson but I don't want to download the database from the server I just want to read it. The Client program is going to be downloading other files, but not the database. Thanks anyway, if you know how can I achieve this, let me know ;)

Comment: You need to download it before you can read it. The database needs to be accessible via a `java.io.File` object, and I'm pretty sure that there is no way to do that directly over an FTP connection.

Comment: Ok. so there is no way I can use the driver and specify the server and its port for example: jdbc:ucanaccess:ip address:port/database ??

Comment: Not directly, no. I've heard of people setting up a JDBC Proxy and using UCanAccess on the server side to manipulate the database, but that is more involved than simply establishing an FTP connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am fairly certain that there is no way to have UCanAccess directly open a database file that resides on an FTP server. Even mechanisms like [Apache Commons VFS](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-vfs/index.html) apparently do not offer a way to directly manipulate or convert a remote file into a `java.io.File` object.

Therefore you will need to download the database file first, and then include the absolute path of the local copy in the UCanAccess connection URL.